Convert output of a command to lowercase in powershell
I'm running a command in PowerShell to get the list of emails in a distribution group but I need to normalize the list to do some comparisons later and I need them all in lowercase. I've tried multiple instances of .tolower() but nothing seems to work. How can I achieve this?
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId [REDACTED] | Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $True |Select-Object UserPrincipalName | Sort-Object UserPrincipalName
This gives me the output:
UserPrincipalName
-----------------
First.Name@redacted.com
Jane.Doe@redacted.com
johnsmith@redacted.com
That.Person@redacted.com

I want them all in lowercase and, since we're already here, without the header "UserPrincipalName -----------------" as well. Thanks in advance.
Tried adding "tolower.()" on multiple different positions in the string. None worked. I'm getting an error that tolower is not recognized, but couldn't find how to install it
tolower. : The term 'tolower.' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ tolower.(Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId [REDACTED] ...
+ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tolower.:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Out of curiosity, what made you think adding tolower.() would do the trick here?

You're using Select-Object in this case to create new objects having a property name UserPrincipalName. If you want to output strings instead, you can use ForEach-Object to expand on each .UserPrincipalName value:
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId [REDACTED] |
    Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $True |
    ForEach-Object { $_.UserPrincipalName.ToLower() } |
    Sort-Object


@MathiasR.Jessen woops, didnt read the "without the header UserPrincipalName...". Thanks!

@MathiasR.Jessen thanks again :P trying to do too many things at the same time

Thank you!! This did the trick. It looks ugly as hell, but it works and that's all that matters!

A variation on @Santiago Squarzon's answer
Get-AzureADGroup -ObjectId [REDACTED] |       
    Get-AzureADGroupMember -All $True |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserPrincipalName |
    ForEach-Object ToLower

It's a bit less efficient but, in my opinion, looks better.
(as in: it's a bit easier to read)
